# Safari and Chrome background positioning is not the same

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

So I made a page with a full size background using the code from this site:
https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

I have also added `background-position:center bottom;` and `background-attachment:fixed;` so that the bottom of the background image is always showing.

It works perfectly fine on Chrome, but on Safari the bottom of the background image is getting cut off a bit. Is there any way I can make it so it looks the same on both browsers?

Comment: I've also just come across this, were you ever able to figure this out?

Comment: Sorry. I have not. I read some articles about adding:

-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

but that didn't help. I just ended up using a new asset that worked with both browsers. Sorry!

Comment: I understand, we ended up using something different too. Thanks for the reply